# Как валидировать несколько однотипных форм одной функцией?

Tags: javascript

Есть код для валидации одной формы, как мне автоматизировать его, чтобы применялся для каждой формы на сайте?

```js
const form = document.querySelector('.form');
const formInputs = form.querySelectorAll('input');
const checkbox = form.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]');

form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  const emptyInputs = Array.from(formInputs).filter((e) => e.value === '');

  formInputs.forEach(function(e) {
    if (e.value === '') {
      e.parentNode.classList.add('error');
    } else {
      e.parentNode.classList.remove('error');
    }

    if (!checkbox.checked) {
      checkbox.classList.add('error');
    } else {
      checkbox.classList.remove('error');
    }
  });

  if (emptyInputs.length !== 0) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Comment: А у вас данный скрипт подходит для валидации всех форм на сайте? Меня смущает, что вы отбираете все input на сайте. Возможно вы грузите разные страницы?

Comment: Так я у одной формы все input отбираю

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это можно сделать, вынеся функционал валидации в отдельную фукнкцию и именно эту функцию передавать в **addEventListener**

```
const form = document.querySelector('.form');
form.addEventListener('submit', formValidator);

function formValidator(e) {
  const formInputs = this.querySelectorAll('input');
  const checkbox = this.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]');
  
  const emptyInputs = Array.from(formInputs).filter((e) => e.value === '');

  formInputs.forEach(function(e) {
    if (e.value === '') {
      e.parentNode.classList.add('error');
    } else {
      e.parentNode.classList.remove('error');
    }

    if (!checkbox.checked) {
      checkbox.classList.add('error');
    } else {
      checkbox.classList.remove('error');
    }
  });

  if (emptyInputs.length !== 0) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

Обратите внимание, что для отбора input'ов используется контекст **this**

Comment: Спасибо большое.